# Linux: SSH/SCP Ask for id_dsa passphrase even in key-less connections

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, scp, passphrase

I have a public/private key pair for ssh connections to a server S, but now, even if do a ssh to another device that does't need any key authentication, I always have the message:

```
> ssh user@192.168.0.10
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_dsa': 
user@192.168.0.10's password:
```

Usually I hit enter in the first question (leaving it blank) and I type the user's password in the second question.

But as I want to write some scripts to automatize some things, the "Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_dsa': " message bothers me.

Why it appears for every connection request? Can I do something so it won't ask me that for every connection? Just with the server S?

Thanks

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/q/130346/93896):

`ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no host.example.org`

To avoid typing it every single time, you can add something like this to `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host host.example.org
PubkeyAuthentication no
```

Comment: It works, but as I am doing a script in Ruby to perform the scp, It still asks me. I put these lines in /etc/ssh/ssh_conf but it didn't work

Comment: Are you calling `scp` itself, or are you using some library, like `Net::SCP`? If former, `scp -o PubkeyAuthentication=no bluh host.example.org:` works for me. If later, you might need to manually create ssh connection with desired options using `Net::SSH` and use it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Linux ssh-agent to store your keys so you don't have to keep typing it.

[Using ssh-agent to manage your keys](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-6.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I like to type my key if I need to, it seems more secure